# Jumbotron background image is not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

When I am viewing the page on desktop, it's working fine and the image is responsive. When I am viewing the page directly on an iPhone, the image is not correct.

[image: Screenshots of the jumbotron image on a PC and on a phone. The image shows a man in the PC version but the phone shows a blurry close up of the brick wall behind him.]

Index.html

```
  <header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container" id="maincontent" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <h1 class="name">Headline</h1>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                    <span class="skills">Sub-header</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Style.css (freelance.css)

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url("http://vlastapolach.cz/img/expecto.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  height: auto;
}
```

Full code is here: https://github.com/vlastapolach/portfolio

I have tried these, but it is not working correctly on desktop either.

```
background-size: contain;
background-size: auto;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: try including width:100%;

Comment: take a look at the [docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images) . 
```Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element```

Comment: @jmag I added both of them 'max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;' but the same result - on PC it is responsive, but not on mobile.

Comment: @VlastaPo can you remove fixed from this background: url("http://vlastapolach.cz/img/expecto.jpg") no-repeat fixed; The short hand shows The properties that can be set, are: background-color, background-image, background-position, background-size, background-repeat, background-origin, background-clip, and background-attachment. Means you got 2 of them.

Comment: Also try width: 100vw;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shorthand syntax holds background-size to fixed. I have remove the fixed.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background: url("http://vlastapolach.cz/img/expecto.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  height: auto;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container" id="maincontent" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <h1 class="name">Headline</h1>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                    <span class="skills">Sub-header</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you! Removing "fixed" worked. Please, any idea how to make it so the background is on the same place and next section rolls over it.. as it was with "fixed".. but working on phone..?

Comment: Try using media queries for that. Media query will activate CSS properties once hitting a certain screen size.

Comment: Great idea, thank you! It's done and now it's working great on PC and mobile too. Thank you so much. RESOLVED.